# Create start column and end column from a single datetime column

Tags: mysql

I would like to select a start column and an end column from a single MySQL datetime column from a table called tbl. Any suggestions?

What I start with:

```
+---------------------+
|      date_time      |
+---------------------+
| 2012-03-05 10:15:52 |
| 2012-03-05 10:15:53 |
| 2012-03-05 10:15:54 |
+---------------------+
```

Wanted result:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|     start_time      |      end_time       |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2012-03-05 10:15:52 | 2012-03-05 10:15:53 |
| 2012-03-05 10:15:53 | 2012-03-05 10:15:54 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: So if you have values A, B and C, you want A-B and B-C, or do you want to store ranges of time?

Comment: Yes, I would like A-B and B-C, please. Ranges of time are not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT   cur.date_time AS start_time, MIN(nxt.date_time) AS end_time
FROM     my_table AS cur JOIN my_table AS nxt ON nxt.date_time > cur.date_time
GROUP BY cur.date_time
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2207/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
select end_time.date_time as [start], 
    (select 
    min(date_time) -- select smallest value from

    from da start_time --another table instance which i called start_time

        -- taking datetimes earlier than start 
    where start_time.date_time > end_time.date_time

    ) as [end]

from da end_time -- table instance with start time

--dont take last value (end time for that value will be null)
where 
    end_time.date_time < (select max(date_time) from da)
```

My table:

```
TABLE [da]
Id  date_time
1   2012-03-05 10:15:52.000
2   2012-03-05 10:15:53.000
3   2012-03-05 10:15:54.000
```

My result:

```
start                   end
2012-03-05 10:15:52.000 2012-03-05 10:15:53.000
2012-03-05 10:15:53.000 2012-03-05 10:15:54.000
```